# Arduino-LoRa module code doesn't work

Tags: iot, lora

I am trying to develop an Arduino sketch in order to send Temp-humi data from a dht11 sensor to KPN (Dutch) Network throughout a LoRa module (Dragino).
There are plenty of sketches around internet with similar function, but none of them has the right function I expect, since most of them ONLY send a simple 'Hello world' data throughout the ABP or OTAA Keys that the Network provides. In the other hand, I have also found sketches that ONLY makes the temp/humi functionality, withouth having the chance to write the Activation Keys.

So, I am actually trying to join these two codes with these functionalities (Request the Activation Keys to connect with KPN Network, as well as the sender sensor data), and it seems to compile properly, however, it is not sending any data, so probably the code is wrong.

May I get any link to the right one or any recommendation, please?

Many thanks in advance.

Project Code:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Tonibco/Dragino-KPN-Project/blob/master/Dragino_KPN.ino)

Answer (score 0):

I have also had my problems with the Dragino shield and dht11 but i got it working.

My script: https://github.com/FelixKunz/LoraDraginoDHT

I would recommend you to use the RN2483. I've had rarely any troubles with this chip and it is not as expensive as the dragino shields.

en prettige dag

Comment: Many thanks for your code!! It is working properly, at least it is what appears on the console;

Packet queued 37102743: EV_TXCOMPLETE (includes waiting for RX windows) 2400.00

I guess 2400.00 is the Temperature value, is not it?

What about the humidity? Should I write the line...
`float a=(dht.readHumidity()*100);`
above the temperature one?

Comment: yes 2400 is your temperature. the siple reason i multiplied it by 100 is because you cant send float values. it has to be a number without decimal places. If you want to send the humidity you can change `float a=(dht.readTemperature()*100);` to `float a=(dht.readHumidity()*100); `

Comment: The purpose would be to add both values into the code.
So, I think I should change also the variables below the sensor readings, is that right? I am not sure how to code it.

`float a= dht.readHumidity();
float b= dht.readTemperature();

int c=(int)a, (int)c;
  data = c;`

Which API link should I provide to KPN support, in order to send my sensor data to ThinkSpeak platform. As they have already my public channel link, however, there are not changes as of yet.

Many thanks Felix!

Comment: Hi,
I am actually adding into the sketch the chance to send this data to ThingSpeak throughout KPN, nevertheless, no data is showed on ThingSpeak dashboard.
The link below is pointed to my new code. I added the library and variables I thought were the proper ones, however, I didn't manage to send it. 

Sketch link: https://github.com/Tonibco/Dragino-KPN-Project/blob/master/Dragino_KPN.ino

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure your area is covered with a lora? I would suggest you setup a [TTN account](https://account.thethingsnetwork.org/users/login) and try if my original script works with your credentials. I think you have problems with connecting to a Gateway. Do you have an examplescript from KPN/Thingsspeak?  PS: I would not recommend you to post your CannelNumber and ApiKey on the Internet ;D

Comment: I have already tested succesfully your original script with KPN (not Gateway). However, I don't see anything at ThingSpeak. So, what I think is that I didn't modify correctly the script in order to send that data forward ThingSpeak throughout KPN.
KPN is a network provider spread around the whole country (Netherlands), rather than TTN which has limited coverage. In fact, I am able to see data within Hookbin endpoint instead, but my priority must be ThingSpeak, since I can monitorise the data graphically. 
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, It seems that there are not example-scripts with KPN around, I didn't find any of them. In the other hand, it seems that it's working with TTN samples anyway. I tested succesfully the sample from TTN which is sendind a 'Hello world' and, I have also been testing your sample with good results 
So, I was actually adding into your sample the chance to send data to ThingSpeak as well, however it doesn't work. I got the source from this link;
https://github.com/dragino/Arduino-Profile-Examples/blob/master/libraries/Dragino/examples/IoTServer/ThingSpeak/dht11_server/dht11_server.ino

Comment: In the lines ~ 140-150 you have serial.Print. Do you get the temperature in your Serial Monitor? Or do you get another error in the serial Monitor?

Comment: I have add some libraries as well as a parameter ThingSpeak.begin(client); 
However, I am getting the following error:
"Sketch too big; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing it.
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno."

My modifications are based on https://github.com/dragino/Arduino-Profile-Examples/blob/master/libraries/Dragino/examples/IoTServer/ThingSpeak/dht11_server/dht11_server.ino

I am not sure whether that modifications would be useful for my sketch...
Thanks

Comment: The source where I am getting the modificatios is using 2 sketches; Server and Client, as well as YUNClient library, in order to make a bridge among  client/server sketches. However I don't know hot to move this functionlaity to my sketch.

Comment: Your program is too big. You have 31.5KB to use in your Flash. Does it show you how big your code is? Maybe you could try to remove Librarys you don't need. Comment all the #include  lines you don't use.

Comment: What about to split the code into 2 ones, as Dragino use as client and server?
https://github.com/dragino/Arduino-Profile-Examples/tree/master/libraries/Dragino/examples/IoTServer/ThingSpeak

The challenge here would be to add the ABP keys (libraries and functions) on the server sketch in order to send this data by KPN network to ThingSpeak.

What do you think?

Comment: It is too big because I added YunClient library in order to make the function ThingSpeak.begin(client) works, otherwise the sketch would provide me an error related with 'client' parameter...

Comment: Yes you are right, it is probably necessary to split up your code.

Comment: I had just the idea of useing a raspberry pi instead of an arduino. My gateway is a RPi with an Dragino Shield. Maybe you want to use it because you would have more than enough storage on your µSD.

Comment: It seems that I managed to send "something" to ThingSpeak dashboard throughout KPN network (not Gateway). However, it is only sending a '0' value...
I removed the ThingSpeak(client) function as I am not using any client scketch. 
I have got the following advertisement even when I comment  dht library and sending just a static number: "Low memory available, stability problems may occur."

[link](https://github.com/Tonibco/Dragino-KPN-Project/blob/master/Dragino_KPN.ino)

You can see below my steady temperature value '0' :

[lin](https://thingspeak.com/channels/266512/private_show)

Comment: Any suggestion about the code I linked above? Otherwise, I will definetely  use a different LoRa Kit, as you have already recommended me previously...
Many thanks!